# How to benefit from personal unions

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

How to benefit from personal unions? I've played as Lithunia and had union with Poland, but ... as far as I understand at some point Poland will get own king and become separated again.

Is there any way to get union partner become the part of your country?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes half a century, but after that duration the nation leading a personal union can inherit or integrate their subject nation so long as the leading nation has more provinces than the subject country.

Inheritance can occur when a ruler dies. See the hovertip over the king in the diplomacy screen to see the probability statistic. Main influences are Diplomatic Reputation, Stability, and whether the countries share a culture group.

Another option, if the leader in the union has 190+ relations with the subordinate partner, then "Integrate" is a diplomatic process that will get the ball rolling on the integration and is similar to annexation.

Comment: Is there any way that personal union can be broken? I was playing Castile, ruler was Isabella; and Aragon decided to marry her.. and join as junior partner. If Isabella (or that another king) die - will union be kept or?

Comment: That depends on prestige and relations. If Castile's ruler dies while having negative prestige or relations with Aragon, it will become independent, and a new ruler from your dynasty will take over. Also, rebels, if they enforce their demands, can stop the integration process or break the union entirely.

Comment: It really worked this way. The only issues with union is that it keeps your diplomatic relationship occupied and you cannot use it for another royal marriage. And the Integration takes also HUGE amount of time: even with +4 points per month, integrating of Aragon (around 980 points) took almost 20 years... Totally 70 years of the blocked relationship. I feel like I better invaded them. Even though that would cost manpower, army, and administrative monarch point, that could be more effective than waiting 70 years and spending almost a thousand of diplomatic points